# Check with PHP if sending a variable through URL even if it's blank

Tags: php

I want to check with PHP if ?u= exists, even if it hasn't any value assigned.

E.G: `http://website.com/?u=` should return true.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the return value of `isset($_GET['u'])`.

- [`isset` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)